# change dots size in slick.js

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

I try to implement the slick.js slider with dots in my website.
slider dots are very small in size.can i change the size of the dots? or it's default one

my css

```
.slider {
          width: 650px;
          margin: 0 auto;
        }

        img {
          width: 200px;
          height: 200px;
        }
```

my html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="slider-about">
            <div class="slider">
                <div>
                    <img src="resources/image/slide1.jpg">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="resources/image/slide2.jpg">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="resources/image/slide3.jpg">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="resources/image/slide1.jpg">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="resources/image/slide2.jpg">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="resources/image/slide3.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my js :

```
$('.slider').slick({
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 3,
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      cssEase: 'linear'
    });
```

this is dots appered [image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The default theme stylesheet slick-theme.css uses "slick" font-family for the icons. Have uploaded the font files folder to your project?
Or if you do not want to use the "slick" font-family, you can adjust the following CSS rule on line 178 in the slick-theme.css

```
    .slick-dots li button:before
    {
        font-family: 'slick';
        font-size: 6px;
        line-height: 20px;
        ...
    }
```

like this

```
    .slick-dots li button:before
    {
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 20px;
        ...
    }
```